# Where is this extra margin coming from?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

Cant tell where this extra border of space is coming from, havent changed anything, except the java fragment from listfragmwent to fragment, and took out a list view in layout file in favor of RecyclerView. the bordering whitespace is a mystery, as it wasn't there before. I have no margins set in the fragment and the only padding set is padding left in the item
[image: screenshot of bordering whitespace]

fragment xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="501dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.58"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-13dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_newPost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_create_post"
        app:elevation="3dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="6dp"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:id="@+id/progress_user_posts"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

item xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_post_username"
        android:layout_width="261dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="16dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="360dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteY="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_post_time"
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/row_post_username"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="264dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_post_content"
        android:layout_width="353dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/row_post_username"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="16dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="360dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteY="26dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="34dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider_post"
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/row_post_content"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="1dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="344dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteY="61dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RecyclerView has fixed width and height:

```
android:layout_width="350dp"
android:layout_height="501dp"
```

replace with **match_parent** to use all the space:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

then set the desired margin with:

```
android:layout_margin="10dp"
```